# Windows XP drives not opening

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, malware

I had a PC which operating system was Windows XP , I reinstalled the Windows , formatting just the C drive , and had my new version of XP installed there , but when it was installed and I tried to open the other drives (meaning for example D , E , .. ) I got this error :

```
i9wjpqc.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close
```

I trying googling it , and I ended up with knowing it's a malware, so my guess is that my previous OS had this malware on its other drives and the source was located in C , now that I've formatted C , other drives still have the malware, so they can't be opened :(

and suggestion to get the drives to open ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start you machine in safe mode and do a virus scan .

Check music3myear's [blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/10/05/a-super-users-toolbox/) on how to do it if you are not sure.

Although once you have sanitized your machine , you might need to repair your OS .

*Warning*
You might be able to right click on your drives and select **open** to access you r drives , but first ensure that the malware wont damage the files and also disconnect your net as a precaution.